# Concatinate part of two columns

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select name,(name,1,3||phone_no,1,3)from users order by (name);
```

I'm writing a query for the above problem and it is showing error.
Write a to display user name and password. The password should be generated by concatenating first three characters of user name and first three numbers in the phone number and give an alias name as the password. Sort the result based on user name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove extra parenthesis and use substring function

```
select name,substr(name,1,3)|| substr(phone_no,1,3) from users order by name
```

Comment: select Schedule_id, travel_date (date format('yyyy/mm/dd')) as FormattedDate from schedule order by (Schedule_id);